# Issue writing log in database with Nlog with multiple threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, nlog

I noticed an strange issue with Nlog while writing the logs in database through multiple threads.

The issue is that the log for one database is sometimes added in another databse i.e they are sometimes intermixed. Is the method of updating the DbTarget of Nlog not thread safe or i am doing something wrong here ?
Please share your ideas/experience to cope with this.

I am using the same single application for three different customers each having three different database in same server. I have C# windows application where there are 3 threads that are created for 3 different databases. Each thread deals with their own database in such a way as shown here:

```cs
public void StartService()
{
    string conn1 = connectionstring for database1;
    string conn2 = connectionstring for database2;

     Thread ThreadDB1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Process(conn1)));
    Thread ThreadDB2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Process(conn2)));

    ThreadDB1.Start();
    ThreadDB2.Start();
}


public void Process(string domainCon)
{
    this.isActive = true;

    while (this.isActive)
    {
        try
        {
            StartOperation(domainCon);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //since the Nlog has not been initialised for an individual threads that switch per database, 
            //If any error occurs here, log that in event log instead
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
}


public static void StartOperation(string domainCon)
{
    NLogLoggerService loggerService;
    NLogLogger Logger;

    /* Set the "NEW" instance of logger here so that each instance
     * will be per thread (i.e per database) */

    Logger = new NLogLogger("MyAppName_Processor");
    loggerService = new NLogLoggerService(Logger);
    //create the DbTarget that is passed by current thread
    Logger.UpdateNLogDatabase(domainCon);

    // the process to select the records from Db happens here
    ProcessDbRecords(domainCon);

}


ProcessDbRecords(domainCon)
{
    //Records are selected, analyzed processed and saved again in database for each thread

    //the following log is written in database but log of one database is written in another database sometimes

    loggerService.LoggerInfo("The Database has been called for connString: " + domainCon);
}


//in LogService class, i have a method that updates the database target with connectionstring provided in runtime:

public static void UpdateNLogDatabase(string connString)
{
    var config = LogManager.Configuration;
    var dbTarget = (Targets.DatabaseTarget)config.FindTargetByName("Database");
    dbTarget.ConnectionString = connString;
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, you're changing the global configuration, so it'll affect all loggers (I mean, the method is named `ReconfigExistingLoggers` so it kinda gives it away). So a thread that changes the connectionstring of the dbtarget will affect the other threads. I think you need to use a different target for each logger

Comment: Hi @KevinGosse, thx for the reply.
Could you please provide few details how could i achieve a different target for each logger ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea (with most logging frameworks) is not modifying the logging-configuration constantly, but instead inject the wanted context-information:

NLog have several options for how to provide context information:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

You could do it like this with `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`:

```
public void Process(string domainCon)
{
    this.isActive = true;

    NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("ThreadConnectionString", domainCon);

    while (this.isActive)
    {
        try
        {
            StartOperation(domainCon);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //since the Nlog has not been initialised for an individual threads that switch per database, 
            //If any error occurs here, log that in event log instead
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

And then have this in NLog.config:

```
<target type="database" connectionString="${mdlc:item=ThreadConnectionString}">
</target>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer